# Мне нужно хранить число 001. Как?

Tags: c++, переменные, int

Мне нужно хранить числа вида 001, 002 и тд. Как я понял, в `int` такое не сделать, так как он убирает все нули перед самим числом при преобразовании. Всё это нужно мне для корректной поразрядной сортировки, но я не понимаю есть ли возможность хранить эти числа именно в числовой переменной, так как с ними в дальнейшем будут проводиться вычисления. Изначально они находятся в `string`.

Comment: Объясните подробнее, о какой сортировке идёт речь.

Comment: Так почему и дальше не хранить их в string и не обращаться к ним как к элементам массива, типа str = "001", str[0] = '0', str[2] = '1'

Comment: Просто считайте, что нули там есть. Для вашей сортировки ничего не изменится..

Comment: @kleshenki В принципе, да. Идея хорошая. Можно попробовать так. Но всё-таки именно в числовой переменной есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: @V-Mor Поразрядная сортировка от меньшего разряда к большему. Чтобы корректно её производить, я дополнил числа меньшего разряда нулями.

Comment: Нет, числовые переменные отбрасывают незначимые разряды (нули слева целой части и справа от дробной). Объясни, зачем нужен именно числовой тип, может найдется и решение получше

Comment: С какой целью используется данная сортировка? Или произвести эту сортировку и есть цель?

Comment: @kleshenki Хорошо. Ну как я понял, можно и воспользоваться строкой как массивом, тогда и преобразовывать в число не нужно. Однако, можно обойтись и без нулей. Сейчас попробую рассмотреть второй вариант, потому что он убирает лишний код.

Comment: @vp_arth Я могу сделать общий ответ, отметив в нем тех, кто дал советы как поступить? Чтобы закрыть вопрос

Comment: Конечно можете) Оформите ответ так, как считаете нужным.

Answer (score 0):

### Возможные варианты решения проблемы:

1. Можно пользоваться `string` как массивом, чтобы с помощью индексов брать нужные числа.
2. В рамках моей задачи можно просто отбросить данные нули и вообще ими не пользоваться, тк можно обойтись и без них (*Таким вариантом я и воспользуюсь*).

За предложенные варианты спасибо этим людям:
@*kleshenki* и @*vp_arth*